# How can I prove that these two series diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm pretty sure these two series diverge, however I'm not sure at all on how to prove it.

I was trying to find the convergence interval of $2^nx^{n-1}$

Using d'Alembert criterion, I've searched $\lim \frac{2^{n+1}x^n}{2^nx^{n-1}}$ which gave me $2x$

Then the next step if I'm right would be to evaluate for both $x$ where $2x = \pm 1$ ($x=1/2$ and $x=-1/2$) if the series converge or diverge.

Which gives me :

$\{2,2,2,2,2\}$, and 
$\{2,-2,2,-2\}$

How can I prove it they diverge or not ?

Comment: Does it diverge for all x or for the values greater than lets say x=1/8?

Answer (score 0):

For the case $x = -\dfrac{1}{2}$, $a_n = (-1)^{n-1}\cdot 2 \to S_n = 0$ if $n$ is even, and is $2$ if $n$ is odd. Thus $S_n$ does not converge to any number, and the series diverges. The other case is fairly easy.